# SQL Select All Without Values in Another Table

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I'm building an application to manage tools that are on loan to staff members and the way that the table is set up is there has a Tools table which has a unique tool code and serial number and a Loans table that contains the unique tool code and a return date. Each time there is a loan, it creates a new entry, the return date when the loan is created is null.

The query I have at the moment searches for all tools based on a text input. I've tried a lot of code with inner joins with no success and as I'm not extremely experienced with SQL, I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

```
SELECT [Tools].[ToolID], [Tools].[Type], [Tools].[Brand], [Tools].[Serial], [Tools].[Year], [Tools].[Code] FROM [Tools]
WHERE ([Tools].Serial LIKE '%234%' OR [Tools].Code LIKE '%234%')
```

My issue occurs when I'm searching for a tool in the loan database. I want it to show tools from the Tools table that:

A) Have no entries in the loan database (i.e. a new tool)

B) All entries in the database have a return date (tool has been returned)

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Combined the two queries from the answer

```
SELECT [Tools].[ToolID], [Tools].[Type], [Tools].[Brand], [Tools].[Serial], [Tools].[Year], [Tools].[Code] 
FROM [Tools] left outer join
Loan ON [Tools].code = Loan.toolcode
WHERE Loan.toolcode is null AND ([Tools].Code LIKE '%234%' OR [Tools].Serial LIKE '%234%')

UNION

SELECT [Tools].[ToolID], [Tools].[Type], [Tools].[Brand], [Tools].[Serial], [Tools].[Year], [Tools].[Code]
FROM Loan
INNER JOIN Tools ON Tools.Code = Loan.ToolCode
GROUP BY [Tools].[ToolID], [Tools].[Type], [Tools].[Brand], [Tools].[Serial], [Tools].[Year], [Tools].[Code]
HAVING count(returndate) = count(*)
```

Comment: I might be saying something silly, but for each tool, select its equivalents in the loans table, and do a `count()` of that...?

Comment: I had trouble with joining, whenever I did a join, it wouldn't show tools that had no value (My inexperience with SQL is the cause). Gordon Linoff's answer was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show tools that have no entry in the loan database:

```
SELECT t.*
from tools t left outer join
     loans l
     on t.code = l.toolcode WHERE l.toolcode is null;
```

I assume that for the second question, you want all tools where all entries have a return date -- that is, no entry is `NULL`:

```
select l.toolcode
from loans l
group by l.toolcode
having sum(case when returndate is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

This formulation counts up the number of records where the `returndate` is `null` and only returns tools where there are no such records.  An alternative way of writing the same logic is:

```
having count(returndate) = count(*)
```

Comment: Thanks =] Exactly what I needed.

So IS NULL works when there are no entries?

Sorry I can't give you're answer an upvote as I don't have the reputation.