# SQL C# WPF Query Expanded

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I had a query answered here [SQL Select All Without Values in Another Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606335/sql-select-all-without-values-in-another-table).

I've just been asked to integrate the data from another database. This is what I have at the moment.

```
            string _loanSubcontractor = TableNames.Default.LoansSubcontractors;
            string _loanPacific = TableNames.Default.LoansPacific;
            string _tools = TableNames.Default.Tools;
            string _selectStatement = " SELECT [Tools].[Type], [Tools].[Brand], [Tools].[Serial], [Tools].[Year], [Tools].[Code] ";
            string _groupBy = " GROUP BY [Tools].[Type], [Tools].[Brand], [Tools].[Serial], [Tools].[Year], [Tools].[Code], [Tools].[Working] ";
            string _searchItems = " ([Tools].Code LIKE @toolSerial OR [Tools].Serial LIKE @toolSerial) AND ([Tools].[Working] = 'True' OR [Tools].[Working] IS NULL) ";
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(Connection.Default.ConnectionString);
            //Checks the main tool information 
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand getTool = new SqlCommand(
                _selectStatement + "FROM [" + _tools + "] LEFT OUTER JOIN [" + _loanSubcontractor + "] ON " +
                _tools + ".code = [" + _loanSubcontractor + "].ToolCode FULL JOIN [" + _loanPacific + "] ON " + _tools + ".Code = " +
                _loanPacific + ".ToolCode WHERE [" + _loanSubcontractor + "].ToolCode IS NULL AND [" + _loanPacific + "].ToolCode IS NULL AND (" + _searchItems + ")" +
                "UNION " +
            _selectStatement + " FROM [" + _loanSubcontractor + "] INNER JOIN " + _tools + " ON " + _tools + ".Code = [" + _loanSubcontractor + "].ToolCode  " +
                "INNER JOIN " + _loanPacific + " ON " + _loanPacific + ".ToolCode = " + _tools + ".Code " + _groupBy +
                "HAVING (COUNT(" + _loanSubcontractor + ".ReturnDate) = COUNT(*) OR COUNT(" + _loanPacific + ".ReturnDate) = COUNT(*)) " +
                " AND " + _searchItems, myConnection);
            getTool.Parameters.Add("@toolSerial", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "%" + toolSerial + "%";
```

What I have is two loan tables (one for employees and one for subcontractors) because the attribute names are different and the data types are also different. Essentially, I need to check that the tool is working, and the tool is not hired out in either of the loan tables (as shown by the return date being null). There may or may not be a loan in either of the tables.

Also, could someone provide me with a link that shows good formatting techniques for SQL within C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i sagest you use linq to SQL . this is a part of ADO.NET and you can use long query with 100 % acres and easy way

[msdn.microsoft.com for linq to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx)

[LINQ to SQL: .NET Language-Integrated Query for Relational Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)

[Simple LINQ to SQL in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26657/Simple-LINQ-to-SQL-in-C)